# How to insert a resultset of a query to a table in shell script?

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu

I have written a shell script as shown below

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$(msql -h localhost -uroot -proot -e database "SELECT * FROM USERS");

resultdetails=$(msql -h localhost -uroot -proot -e database "SELECT * FROM DETAILS");
```

I need to Insert both the result set from result and resultdetails to a new table "TABLE USERDETAILS".

I have tried lot and searched google for hour but couldn't able to get a solution so any help thanks in advance.

Comment: Modify your SQL queries to put the result set in a new table.

Comment: @Sathish First you check whether DB connection is done. 
For that simply run the script with #!/bin/bash
# connect to test database and query the USERS table
mysql -u root -p root test <<EOF
SELECT * FROM USERS;
EOF 
You should able to see USERS Table Data. If it is proper then try to select one column and see. Let me know the results

Comment: @Jigar The OP obviously already knows how to run a query. Supplying a different way to do that isn't immediately helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the insert ... select ... syntax. Below is a example

```
msql -h localhost -uroot -proot -e database "INSERT into userdetail SELECT  u1, u2, u3, d1, d2, d3 FROM USERS u INNER JOIN DETAILS d ON (u.id=d.user_id)"
```